# how to send mp3 blob as a post request?

Tags: javascript, audio, http-post, blob

I have an audio recorder and i need to send it as a post request in a third party server so it must be mp3.

My blob logs :
size:17981
type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus"

and my code :

```
  async function sendBlob() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("audio-file", getBlob);
    const res = await fetch("/api/whisper", {
      method: "POST",
      // headers: {
      //   "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
      // },
      body: formData,
    });
    const { result } = await res.json();
  }
```

I already tried to create a File() and almost everything, i need to send it as a mp3 file.

I tried to send the blob, to append it in a FormDat() and in a File(), i tried to send the url but the post request only accepts mp3 files (if i upload the file and send it works, but i want to record and send direct)

Answer (score 0):

More information is necessary to understand what is the content of your `getBlob` variable, nevertheless, I noticed three things about your code:

1. 'audio-file' is the parameter name expected by the API you are calling and it hardly is called like that
2. you missed a 3rd parameter in the formData, which is the name of the file
3. prefer using 'audio/mpeg' as your ContentType

### Exemple using React, Axios, react-audio-voice-recorder, and calling a Python API:

**Step 1:** Setup your react-audio-voice-recorder:

```
  import { AudioRecorder } from 'react-audio-voice-recorder';

  ...


  const YourComponent = () => {

  (...)

    return (
          <AudioRecorder
            onRecordingComplete={handleRecordingComplete}
            audioTrackConstraints={{
              noiseSuppression: true,
              echoCancellation: true,
            }}
            downloadOnSavePress={false}
          />
    );
  }
```

**Step 2:** Setup your `handleRecordingComplete` method:

```js
  const handleRecordingComplete = async (blob) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const axiosConfig = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
      }
    };

    // file is the parameter name in the API (example in step 3)
    // blob is your blob file
    // 'audio.mp3' is the name you want your file to have
    formData.append('file', blob, 'audio.mp3');

    await axios.post(API_URL, formData, this.audioConfig)
      .then(async response => {
        const transcriptedText = response.data.response.transcript.text;
        console.log(transcriptedText);
      })
      .catch(exception => console.log(expection));
  };
```

**Step 3:** Check your API code (in my case, in Python, calling openAI to transcript an audio):

```py
async def transcript_audio(audio: BufferedReader) -> SingleQuestionResponse:
    env = get_dotenv()
    openai.api_key = env.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio)

    return {"transcript": transcript}


@router.post("/api/transcript")
async def post_transcript_audio (file: UploadFile)):
    with open(file.filename, 'wb') as buffer:
        buffer.write(file.file.read())

    audio = open(file.filename, 'rb')
    transcripted_audio = await transcript_audio(audio)

    return {'response': transcripted_audio}
```

JIT: Be careful with the naming of the things. `getBlob` gives the idea of an uncalled method. Double-check the name of the expected variable name in your API, because as I said, 'audio-file' doesn't look correct.